# Initiating offline product retrieval with wget for Scihub Copernicus

Tags: batch, copernicus

I need to download a big chunk of Sentinel-2 data which is stored in ESAs Long Term Archive (LTA). I've already added all the products to my cart, but I want to initiate the request for the offline products automatically every 31 minutes in order to save time and nerves.

I thought I could do it with wget but if I do:

```
~$ wget --content-disposition --continue --user="USERNAME" --password="PASSWORD" "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('ID')/$value"
```

All I get is an index file which states, that the file is offline, without initiating the product retrieval.

How can I do this using wget?

Answer (score 2):

I had to escape the $ sign in terminal with a backslash. So:

```
~$ wget --content-disposition --continue --user="USERNAME" --password="PASSWORD" "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products('ID')/\$value"
```

did work for me.